# Is it possible not to get two last elements via nokogiri?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I want to take all `<p>` elements, using this code:

```
novelty.body = page.css('.rt-article p').text
```

but I don't want to get last two `<p>` elements. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

```
page.css('.rt-article p').slice(0...-2).text
```

Notice, there are three dots.

Comment: `page.css('.rt-article p').slice(0...-2).text` works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: `..` is preferable over `...`. It's a readability and maintenance thing. `0..-3` vs. `0...-2`: Which requires more mental gymnastics to figure out what's happening?